# Am I running into a CORS issue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I have followed [this](https://scotch.io/@neo/getting-started-with-laravel-passport) tutorial to set up Laravel & Laravel Passport.
In order to test calls to my api I used this test client in a different directory on my server:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

try {
    $response = $client->post('http://todos.test/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => 2,
        // The secret generated when you ran: php artisan passport:install
        'client_secret' => 'fx5I3bspHpnuqfHFtvdQuppAzdXC7nJclMi2ESXj',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'johndoe@scotch.io',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'scope' => '*',
    ]
]);

// You'd typically save this payload in the session
$auth = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );

$response = $client->get('http://todos.test/api/todos', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$auth->access_token,
    ]
]);

$todos = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );

$todoList = "";
foreach ($todos as $todo) {
    $todoList .= "<li>{$todo->task}".($todo->done ? '✅' : '')."</li>";
}

echo "<ul>{$todoList}</ul>";

} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
   echo "Unable to retrieve access token.";
}
```

This worked and both requests give a valid response. However when I put this code in a new react native app (of course in javascript) the first request returns a `200` an gives me back a client secret.

Now when I do the second call I get an error:`401 Unauthorized`. I was wondering if this has to do with CORS or am i looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Sorry that url is not accurate. I use a .test domain

Answer (score -1):

no! 
this is not CORS issue, you just haven't unauthorized, check your access_token if is it valid and not expired.

Comment: Hi how can i check if the access token is valid?

Comment: you have an authentication error, automatically it means that your access token is not valid. and that not a CORS issue. 
to see the request that your are sending into your back-end, click right on your page, and click on Inspect Element, and go to the Network tab. click on XRH to see only the ajax requests, now here you can see your request response, header, params(like the access token that you are sending) ..etc.